# How to filter for multiple values in 3D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, filtering

I need to filter a dataset that contains brain image intensity values and normalized values, layer labels and segmentation labels [brain region]. For example, if the unique values for the regions are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6, then I want to remove the rows containing 2 and 4.

I cant't show original dataset, so I generated simplified version to make it clear [first and second column are image values, third column is a brain region:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng

array = np.linspace(0, 6, num = 128)

ls = []

for i in array:

  arr = np.round(i)
  ls.append(arr)

array = np.asanyarray(ls)
array1 = default_rng(42).random((1, 128, 2))

array = array[None, :, None]
arr = np.concatenate((array1, array), axis=2)
```

```
# Output example:

array([[[0.77395605, 0.43887844, 0.        ],
        [0.85859792, 0.69736803, 0.        ],
        [0.09417735, 0.97562235, 0.        ],
        [0.7611397 , 0.78606431, 0.        ],
        [0.12811363, 0.45038594, 0.        ],
        [0.37079802, 0.92676499, 0.        ],
        [0.64386512, 0.82276161, 0.        ],
        [0.4434142 , 0.22723872, 0.        ],
        [0.55458479, 0.06381726, 0.        ],
        [0.82763117, 0.6316644 , 0.        ],
        [0.75808774, 0.35452597, 0.        ],
        [0.97069802, 0.89312112, 1.        ],
        [0.7783835 , 0.19463871, 1.        ],
        [0.466721  , 0.04380377, 1.        ],
        [0.15428949, 0.68304895, 1.        ],
        [0.74476216, 0.96750973, 1.        ],
        [0.32582536, 0.37045971, 1.        ],
        [0.46955581, 0.18947136, 1.        ],
        [0.12992151, 0.47570493, 1.        ],
        [0.22690935, 0.66981399, 1.        ],
```

I tried to filter the data by combining multiple conditions using the AND operator, but this is not what I want, given that there will be more regions to exclude in the future.

```
# constant
profile_length = 128

# filtering
# make array without region 2 and 4
condition = arr[np.where((arr[:, :, 2] != 2) & (arr[:, :, 2] != 4))]
```

In general I need something that does not need to be dissected for further conditions. Is there any solution?

Comment: How about `np.where(arr[:, :, 2] not in filter_list)` with `filter_list` being the list of values you want to filter ?

Comment: @rochard4u Just tried your solution and ValueError occured "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()".